# maintaining an input / output log in R

Tags: r, session, logging

Is there an easy way to have R record all input and output from your R session to disk while you are working with R interactively?

In `R.app` on `Mac OS X` I can do a `File->Save...`, but it isn't much help in recovering the commands I had entered when R crashes.

I have tried using `sink(...,split=T)`, but it doesn't seem to do exactly what I am looking for.

Answer (score 6):

Many of us use ESS / Emacs for this very reason.  Saving old sessions with extension '.Rt' even gives you mode-specific commands for re-running parts of your session.

Answer (score 4):

Greg Snow wrote recently on the R-help list (a very valuable resource, SO R people!):

"You may also want to look at ?TeachingDemos::txtStart as an alternative to sink, one advantage is that the commands as well as the output can be included.  With a little more work you can also include graphical output into a transcript file."

[r-help](http://www.nabble.com/Output-to-screen-and-file-at-the-same-time-td24954441.html)

Answer (score 1):

Check out the [savehistory() command](http://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-patched/library/utils/html/savehistory.html)

Comment: afaik savehistory does not save the output of the session, as desired by the Eytan.

Comment: it saves the input and it does not depend on the editor one uses

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure yet how to answer an answer, but there is an updated version of Ranke's vim r-plugin called r-plugin2 available [here](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=2628). It seems more user-friendly and robust than the original.

Answer (score 0):

Emacs is good, but for those of us with a vi preference there's the vim-r plugin at:

http://www.uft.uni-bremen.de/chemie/ranke/index.php?page=vim_R_linux

It works brilliantly and has a tiny memory footprint.