# How do you sink input and output to a text file in R?

Tags: r

How do you sink both the console input and the console output to a text file?
Take the following code:

```
sink("temp.txt")
1:10
sink()
```

It will write a text file that looks like this:

```
[1]  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9 10
```

But how do I create a text file that looks like this:

```
>   1:10
 [1]  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9 10
```

I've looked at ?sink and searched [R-help](http://tolstoy.newcastle.edu.au/R/help/05/06/7322.html).
I've also read: [maintaining an input / output log in R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1343442/maintaining-an-input-output-log-in-r)

If it makes a difference, I'm using StatET and Eclipse.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

```
library(TeachingDemos)

txtStart("temp.txt")
1:10
txtStop()
```

The text file now looks like

```
> 1:10
 [1]  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9 10
```

Comment: Thanks. It seems to work well. I'm surprised that a similar function is not a part of Base R.

Comment: @George Dontas, is this still necessary, 5 years on ?  Can it sink `help( "xx" )` to a file ?

Answer (score 6):

If you save an R script file instead of inputing your commands into an interactive session, you can also run the following from the command line (on *nix systems):

```
R --no-save --quiet < /path/to/script.R > /path/to/output.txt
```

This will create the file "output.txt" and save all input (including comments) and output from the R script into it.