# How to write an R program that copies its source code to a file?

Tags: r

I'm writing an R script whose contents can change from time to time.  It would be really helpful if I could insert a command that would copy the current contents of the script to a file, so I can go back later and see exactly what commands I executed during that run of the code.

How can I do this?

Comment: If you don't want to use a version control system like git, you could stick something like this somewhere in your script `system(sprintf("cp my_script.R my_script_%s.R", format(Sys.time(), '%Y_%m_%d_%H_%m')))` make sure you save the script and then `source` it. this line will make a copy of your script and rename it with the current date/time

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this with the teaching demos package:

```
    install.packages("TeachingDemos")
    library(TeachingDemos)

    #Will write to a file in the working directory
    txtStart("captureCode.txt")

    #This comment will not appear in the file, all commands and output will
    Sys.Date() 

    #This command ends writing to the file
    txtStop()
```

[Source](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2983433/how-do-you-sink-input-and-output-to-a-text-file-in-r)

Comment: In addition, lots of cool options / related functions `?txtStart`