# Save the output of an r script including its commands

Tags: r, output, sink

I want to save a part of my r script output including the commands into a text file. I know  `sink()` but it does not include the commands or I could not find a specific option to do that.

Is there any possibility to capture the commands **and** its ouput **within** an r session. Simply write an Rmd or capture the output within the console is not the solution at the moment.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to write an R program that copies its source code to a file?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31616322/how-to-write-an-r-program-that-copies-its-source-code-to-a-file)

Comment: I don't know what you want to do with the text file, but knitr might be of interest to you.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You are probably looking for the `TeachingDemos` package. Documentation can be found [here](http://www.inside-r.org/packages/cran/teachingdemos/docs/etxtStart).

Example:

```
library(TeachingDemos)

txtStart("test.txt")
# Your code
txtStop()
```

This should write both your command input and output to a file called `test.txt`.

Comment: That's almost exactly what I was looking for. Thank you. What would be nice is to include also the code comments, not just normal text comments.  Is there any possibility I can extend the library with such a function? Simply overwrite the function `txtComment(...)` is leading to R2txt not found.

Comment: @MarkusGraf, this does not seem to be currently possible. The `txtComment` function seems to be what you are looking for, however you should not overwrite it. Instead you should call it with the comment text as an argument. So, this would require some changes to your code, but can achieve what you want.

Answer (score 1):

If you're working interactively, here's one idea. It was this specific problem for which I created the `sinkstart()` function in [the **rite** package](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/rite/index.html). Basically, this creates a pop-up tcl/tk widget that you can write commands and output to. Here's a screenshot to give you a feel:

[image]

There are just two relevant functions: `sinkstart()` starts the sink; `sinkstop()` turns it off. You can toggle back and forth to selectively write to the widget. Then you can just save the contents with a right-click or a key shortcut.